# OnClick UPDATE SQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql

I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hello($id)
{
alert($id);
}
</script>
```

AND

```
<span onclick="hello('.$a['id'].');" data-id="'.$a['id'].'" data-status="'.$a['status'].'" class="badge '.(($a['status'] == 0)?'red':'green').'">'.date('d.m', $a['date']).'</span>
```

Now , i need to change status with onclick, If status is 0 change with 1 , if status is 1 change with 0

how i run this : `$sql = "UPDATE erp_absente SET status= 1 or 0 WHERE id=".$id;`
and what code is on  status value.

Answer (score 0):

use an ajax call.

set up a php script to take those commands as post data, and have the ajax call run in the onClick.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
```

});

Comment: Thanks but , problem it is i don't know JS and Ajax, maiby 10%... i try to make something with this code.. no results